# Icons not showing in bottom nav bar

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationbar

[activity_home.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zLeU.jpg)I can't figure out why the icons for my bottom nav bar are not showing. The height is set to wrap content and it is 0dp tall, telling me there are no Icons at all. Here is the code:

**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_myEvents"
        android:title="My Events"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_myConversations"
        android:title="My Conversations"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_conversations"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activityHome"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="log out"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnLogOut"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

(I know the constraints are all crazy right now, pls ignore!)

Comment: post your screen

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Are you sure you are on same activity that uses this layout?

Comment: your code is correct

Comment: how do I post my screen on here?

Comment: i think that did it

Comment: it only lets me put up one pic, link in beginning of question

Comment: it might be because of the color of the window. try adding android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground". Also try changing your constraints so the bottom nav menu is on the bottom of the screen. Also, are you deploying it on an emulator or device? or just looking at it on your preview?

Comment: after I ran it on the emulator it all updated and is working properly! thanks, I feel dumb but better!